# How to Preventing Host Header Attack in ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, security

f we send a request from any host like example.com our server gives back a HTTP 1.1 200 OK response status.

In correct condition it should show either 302, 400 or 404 error message (not found response) status. At current condition it is showing 200 OK response message, when its send through our host like xx.xxx.xx.xx.

For example, if we sent this request:

```
GET /web/ HTTP/1.1 
**Host: example.com** 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Connection: close Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

We get this response:

```
**HTTP/1.1 200 OK** 
Date: Thu, 02 Mar 2017 15:23:20 GMT 
Server: figi_Server 
X-Frame-Options: deny Strict-Transport-Security: 1 Vary: Accept-Encoding X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Using these specs:

> OS:  Ubuntu 14.04. Web server:  Apache 2.2. Virtual machine running
> both.

Please go through Screen Shot Of Issue for better Understanding of Issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check your virtual host configuration in Apache and make sure that there is no default virtual host.

If there is a default virtual host in the settings, then any requests to the Web server will succeed.

See [the Apache configuration for virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) for more.